# The use od third conditional

Tags: conditionals

Can we use simple and continuous forms in both clauses with 3 conditional

1 If I had played I would have won

2 IF I had played I would have been winning

3 Id I had been playing I would have been winning

4 If I had been playing I would have won

My question is if using 3 conditional all forms given by me are right.

Comment: No. If you _win_ you are the victor in a race or game, if you _are winning_ the event is still in progress and you appear highly likely to win.

Comment: Do they all make sense or some are just wrong?

Comment: (1) is the most natural; (4) is possible, (2) and (3) don't work for the reason I gave. (Well, I suppose someone _might_ say while watching a long chess game "If I had been playing I would have been winning by now*.)

Comment: What if I change something 2 I had been there I would have been wining ? Could you explain yet again why 3 doesn't work I didn't get that?

Comment: I've told you that you would only say _I am winning_ when the game, race or whatever hasn't finished yet (but you are ahead of most of the other runners). "If I had been there/had been playing I would have been winning" just seems to me an extremely unlikely thing for anyone to say.

Comment: Note, I hope you're not trying to extrapolate rules from this to apply to all situations. Some of the things that don't work here don't work *for this set of verbs*. "If I had been driving I would have been paying attention" is fine.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments explain- all of them can be used, however, 1 and 4 sound the least awkward. ‘To win’ is a completed state, while Andy’s example, paying attention, is an action done consistently. So, saying ‘I would have been winning’ might sound strange as it’s more straightforward to say you would have won.

Comment: If I had seen it I would have been screaming. Is this example fine and why?

Comment: Yes! ‘Screaming’ just expresses an ongoing action- if you want to specifically express one single scream ‘screamed’ also works